# replacing words in PHP document

Tags: php

```html
$festa = mysql_result($result,$i,"festa");
   $data = mysql_result($result,$i,"data");
   $luogo = mysql_result($result,$i,"luogo");
   $prezzo = mysql_result($result,$i,"prezzo");
   $dettagli = mysql_result($result,$i,"dettagli");
   $bus = mysql_result($result,$i,"bus");
   $organizzatore = mysql_result($result,$i,"organizzatore");
      
      $dettagli= ereg_replace("*TITOLO", '<font color="#E3161A">', $dettagli); 
      $dettagli= ereg_replace("*/TITOLO", "</font>", $dettagli);
      
      
        
      echo'<div id="latestadded"> <div class="titlebarpub"> #PUBBLICITA </div> <div class="pubblicita3"><script type="text/javascript">
document.write(\'<s\'+\'cript type="text/javascript" src="http://ad.altervista.org/js.ad/size=728X90/r=\'+new Date().getTime()+\'"></s\'+\'cript>\');
</script></div></div><br>';
   echo "  <div class='titlebarpe'>
    #$numerofesta $festa 
    <br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <img src='fotoorganizzatori/$organizzatore.png' class='immaginefestape'/>
    <br>
   
    <div class='informazionibase'>
    <p align='left' style='margin-left: 10%;'>
    <font color='#EBE440' class='soloformimpact'>DATA EVENTO : </font> $data <br>
    <font color='#EBE440' class='soloformimpact'>LUOGO : </font> $luogo <br>
    <font color='#EBE440' class='soloformimpact'>COSTO FESTA : </font>$prezzo <br>
    </div>
    </p>
    
    <div class='altreinformazioni'>
    
    
    <font color='#EBE440' font-size:'+2' class='soloformimpact'> TUTTE LE ALTRE INFORMAZIONI </font><br>
    <font color='#000000' class='soloformimpact'> <p align='left' style='margin-left: 10%;'> $dettagli </p> </font> <br>
    </p>
    </div>
    
    
    ";
   /*PAGINA EVENTO*/ ?>
```

why the ereg_replace dosen't work?
in my page if i put the ereg_replace it  shows me nothing
i searched in other sites to solve this problem
but i can't find where is my error
and i don't know what i do to solve this problem, thank you if you can help me

Comment: `ereg_` functions are deprecated (for a long time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try str_replace() instead:

```
$dettagli = str_replace("TITOLO","<font color=\"#E3161A\">", $dettagli);
$dettagli = str_replace("/TITOLO","</font>", $dettagli);
```